# cant get json data from url not localhost

Tags: jquery, json

ovar . tk/server.php:

```
[{"nama":"cilok","tempat":"Jajanan cilok dapat di temukan di daerah sekitar gerbang     FAPET","gambar":"cilok.jpg"},{"nama":"martabak","tempat":"Jajanan martabak dapat di temukan di daerah pasar Dinoyo lama","gambar":"martabak.jpg"},{"nama":"cwie mi","tempat":"Jajanan cwie mi dapat di temukan di daerah jalan sumbersari gang 3 ","gambar":"martabak.jpg"},{"nama":"mcd","tempat":"Restoran Mc Donalds dapat di temukan di daerah pasar Dinoyo lama","gambar":"martabak.jpg"},{"nama":"mcd","tempat":"Tidak Ditemukan","gambar":""}]
```

and my code is test.html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://ovar.tk/server.php",function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field.nama + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>    
<button>Get JSON data</button>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

nothing happen when i click the button, it show the data when the url is localhost 
im newbie in getting json data, so please help me! Thank you all! :D

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're having a cross-origin resource sharing problem, take a look at [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/). You should be using `JSONP` to solve the problem by adding

```
 dataType: 'jsonp'
```

to your request.

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
     url:"http://ovar.tk/server.php",
     dataType: 'jsonp', 
     success:function(json){
         // do stuff with json 
         alert("Success");
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you may be falling foul of the "[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)" which stops JavaScript in regular pages loading data from servers other than the one which the page came from.